# Read JSON files using RDD with S3 URIs

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, amazon-s3

In general, what I'm trying to do is:

1. Resolve AWS S3 json URIs by querying the JavaEsSpark
   (elasticsearch-hadoop)
2. With the resolved `JavaRDD<String>` I would like to read
   every json file for further processing within the same Spark cluster

Unfortunately I'm struggling with loading jsons directly using above-mentioned RDD. Right now I'm only able to collect the URIs into the driver's memory and read them later using the cluster. It's memory and CPU inefficient though (there might be a lot of URIs).

Do you have any idea how to do this without merging the data into a single point in the process? Or maybe I should consider completely different solutions (taking in mind that Spark, S3 and ES are here to stay)?

Here's the snippet of my current solution:

```
String[] uris = JavaEsSpark.esJsonRDD(sparkContext, esResource, esQuery)
    .keys() // let's assume s3 ids are here
    .map(this::createS3Uri)
    .collect();
Dataset<Row> jsons = sparkSession.read().json(uris);
// some further process here
```

Comment: `read().json` doesn't take a String[], last time I checked. And you can't guarantee that all uris have the same schema for a Dataset to be made from them, so I'd be surprised if this were possible without an actual loop

Comment: @cricket_007: it does, actually: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#json-java.lang.String...- I can also be sure about my URIs and JSONs - everything is consistent in this case.

Comment: _Right now I'm only able to collect the URIs into the driver's memory and read them later using the cluster. It's memory and CPU inefficient though (there might be a lot of URIs)_ - if number of files is large enough to be a problem with collect, there is a good chance it will be problematic for `read.json` anyway. It sounds to me, you should focus on limiting number of files first (some consolidation process?).

Comment: Ah. Added in Spark 2. Okay, so what processing are you doing? Any transforms? Like getting all distinct uris  or you are just collecting them to the driver immediately?

Comment: Sorry for ambiguity. I have to resolve events from the ES cluster using desired criteria. After that I need to resolve JSONs for that events. Every JSON is available in S3 bucket under the id stored within the event. At the end I need to transform and aggregate the data from such JSONs and generate single-file output report. There might be even 15mln events matching the given criteria in the ElasticSearch.